# How to filter certain URLs from a list based on keywords

Tags: python, list

I am having problem with removing certain URLs from a list in Python. I want to know the easiest and quickest way.

I got a list of URLs returned from google search API. I want to remove all the websites which have the domain `"trip advisor"`, `"facebook"`, `"instagram"`, `"twitter"` and `"ebag"`.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```py
page_urls = ['https://the1955club.com/', 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g1842228-d10140470-Reviews-The_1955_Club-Walton_On_Thames_Surrey_England.html']
# print('page_urls', page_urls)

all_urls = []

for address in page_urls:
    url = urlparse(address)
    new_url = url.netloc
    all_urls.append(new_url)

all_urls.remove('www.tripadvisor.com')
all_urls.remove('tripadvisor.com')
```

I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: How about `all_urls = [url for url in all_urls if 'tripadvisor.com' not in url]`?

Comment: You try to remove `tripadvisor.com` twice.

Comment: what does "all_urls = [url for url in all_urls if 'tripadvisor.com' not in url]" do?

Comment: can i do "all_urls = [url for url in all_urls if 'tripadvisor.com' and 'facebook.com' not in url]"  to check another website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse

page_urls = [
    "https://the1955club.com/",
    "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g1842228-d10140470-Reviews-The_1955_Club-Walton_On_Thames_Surrey_England.html",
]

forbiddens = ["facebook", "instagram", "twitter", "tripadvisor"]


def check_url(url):
    parsed_url = urlparse(url).netloc
    return not any(item in parsed_url for item in forbiddens)


valid_urls = [url for url in page_urls if check_url(url)]
print(valid_urls)
```

Basically you first parse the URL with `urllib.parse.urlparse` and get the `netloc` part of it. Next you iterate through your forbidden names and check to see if any of them is in the netloc. `check_url` does the filtering.

This of course doesn't remove URLs from `page_urls`, it creates new one. But you can do this if you want to mutate that list:

```py
page_urls[:] = [url for url in page_urls if check_url(url)]
print(page_urls)
```